# Python function only runs once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pre-processing a csv file and want to output 3 dictionaries comprised of the csv file data filtered by a field.

The set-up is:

```
import csv
from m_functions import region_goals    

csvFile = # a file path

mnDict = dict()
nlDict = dict()
neDict = dict()

# READ CSV
weekList = csv.reader(open(csvFile))

# CREATE DICTIONARY FOR THIS WEEK AND REGION
region_goals(weekList, "STR1", neDict)
region_goals(weekList, "STR2", mnDict)
region_goals(weekList, "STR3", nlDict)
```

The region_goals function is:

```
def region_goals(csv, region, region_dictionary):
    firstline = True
    for row in csv:
        if firstline:
            firstline = False
            continue
        if row[14] == region:
            if row[16] not in region_dictionary:
                region_dictionary[row[16]] = float(row[6])
            else:
                region_dictionary[row[16]] += float(row[6])
        else:
            continue
    return region_dictionary
```

The output is always as expected for the first use of the function.  The second 2 times I use the function, empty dictionaries are returned.

I'm sure this is me missing something small but I am new to python and have been struggling to fix this for a while.  Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: You've already iterated through the file in the first call, so subsequent calls don't have anything to read through.  You either need to move the call to `weekList = csv.reader(open(csvFile))` into the function (so the file is reopened) or you can try `weekList.seek(0)` if the csv.reader class supports it.

Comment: If the function returns three dictionaries, then clearly it is run three times.

Comment: Nice try Arnab, but if you look at the above, three empty dictionaries are created during the set-up.

Comment: g.d.d.c - thanks I thought it best to include the reader in the method and it worked like a charm - mucho gracias knew it was something with my logic

Comment: @MarcoCarlitoIII : yes, but you say that it returns three dictionaries. That means you call the function three times and check what it returns. The dictionary might well have been instantiated before, but it is still returned thrice (due to the three calls to the function).

Comment: as a sidenote, you don't need the `firstLine` variable/check. Simply do 
`for row in weekList[0:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first pass, you're at the end of your CSV file and there's nothing left to read, so you need to re-open it.

Also, it's not the best idea to modify object in-place with functions. It's better to return a new object each time.

```
import csv
from m_functions import region_goals    

csvFile = # a file path

regions = ['STR1', 'STR2', 'STR3']
for region in regions:
    with csv.reader(open(csvFile)) as weekList:
        region_dict = dict()
        output = region_goals(weekList, region, region_dict )
```

Answer (score 1):

You already read the file after the first function call, you could do a ´seek(0)´ on the opened file. Try something like this:

```
# READ CSV
f = open(csvFile)
weekList = csv.reader(f)

region_goals(weekList, "STR1", neDict)
f.seek(0)
region_goals(weekList, "STR2", mnDict)
```

EDIT:
If the file is no too big and/or you handle more memory useage, you could do something like:

```
# READ CSV
weekList = list(csv.reader(open(csvFile)))
```

And your code should work, but keep in mind the whole file will be loaded to memory.

The best solution would be to refactor things to populate those three dicts in one pass and call that function once.

Comment: It should probably be `f = open(csvFile)`.

Comment: do you mean `weekList.seek(0)`?

Comment: I have to think you'd be better off reading the file one time into a `list` and then passing that *list* into the function, rather than re-reading the file 3 times.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Well maybe that is assuming too much, we don't know how big that file is to load it to memory, and we know it hase many columns OP is not using. Maybe OP can refactor that code to populate those dicts in one pass.

Comment: but `f` is just a string of the filename, right? the actual fileio object is `weekList`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PaulH Oh what's missing is the assignment! f = open(csvFile)

Answer (score 1):

Your title is wrong in the sense, that the function is obviously executed multiple times. Otherwise you would not get back empty dicts. The reason for the empty dicts is, that `csv.reader` returns already an object that behaves like an iterator. So you can iterate it only once. The next two calls will not get any more data. You have to call `csv.reader` again or you have to read the data into memory and process it three times.

Answer (score 0):

Per  g.d.d.c's suggestion I modified the function to include the reader and pass the file location rather than the read-in csv.

```
import csv


def region_goals(csvfile, region, region_dictionary):
    weeklist = csv.reader(open(csvfile))
    firstline = True
    for row in weeklist:
        if firstline:
            firstline = False
            continue
        if row[14] == region:
            if row[16] not in region_dictionary:
                region_dictionary[row[16]] = float(row[6])
            else:
                region_dictionary[row[16]] += float(row[6])
        else:
            continue
    return region_dictionary
```

Thank you for all responses!